# Swift: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary, swift5

I have this code:

```
let active: NSString = NSString.init()

for value in 0..<(array.count + 1){
                        let validateData: NSDictionary = array.object(at: value) as! NSDictionary
                        
                        let key: NSString = validateData.object(forKey: "clave") as! NSString
                        let name: NSString = validateData.object(forKey: "nombre") as! NSString
                      
                        active = validateData.object(forKey: "activo") as! NSString
                        
                        let sucursal_ID: NSString = validateData.object(forKey: "id_sucursal") as! NSString
                        let sucursal_Name: NSString = validateData.object(forKey: "nombre_sucursal") as! NSString
                     
                        if !(key.isEqual(to: "")){
                            NSLog("clave: %@", key)
                            NSLog("nombre: %@", name)
                            
                            actives?.add(active)
                            names?.add(name)
                            keys?.add(key)
                            sucursalesID?.add(sucursal_ID)
                            if sucursal_Name != "" {
                                NSLog("Es bimbo")
                                sucursalesNames?.add(sucursal_Name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

> I am getting the error:
>
> > Could not cast value of type '__NSFCNumber' to 'NSString' in line `active = validateData.object(forKey: "activo") as! NSString` ** Thread 1: signal SIGABRT  **

Why is that happening? And what can I do to solve it

Comment: Why do you believe that the value for "activo" is a string?  (The program is finding a number instead.)

Comment: `validateData.object(forKey: "activo")` is a `NSNumber`, not a `NSString` that's what means the error. So consider it as a `NSNumber` and handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!, in your opinion would a downcast to a NSString be a smart solution?

Comment: The code looks like a literal *translation* from Objective-C code. Please stop using the *objective-c-ish* `NS..` classes. This is Swift. Use native types (`String` and `[String:Any]`) and key subscription (`validateData["activo"] `). Cast `activo` to `Bool` or `Int`. And the Swift compiler can infer the types. All annotations are redundant.

Comment: Force-casting to `NSString` is a bad idea because your value is not a string. That's why your code is crashing. Really the whole idea of storing this data in `NS/Dictionaries` is just not good, if you're receiving the data from a server you should be decoding it into Swift types.

Comment: Right, thanks y'all